# Has the "demonstrate minimal understanding" flag been removed?

Tags: support

The most useful flag I've found on SO is the "*demonstrate minimal understanding*" one, as there are a high number of people just asking for test questions to be answered with code without trying it themselves for example.

For the last couple of days I've been trying to use this flag and it seems to be gone from my selection; has it been removed? Have I abused it in some way? Or is there a limit to how many times we can use it in a specified time frame?